# RestAPI passing images as base64 strings in POST request

Tags: android, node.js, rest

I'm building a RestAPI for a mobile application where you can upload images and stuff.

My question was about *how* you pass actual images to the RestAPI.
My design is: 
You have an endpoint `/api/data/createReport`
This endpoint accepts a field called `images` which is a comma-separated list of strings, which are the base64 encoded images.
I would then split the strings and store them somewhere (or maybe re-encode them as images).

Is this a good design?
Is it safe?
Is it performant?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are several things to take into account when using server image storage. There are available cloud solutions with REST Apis that you can set up in your app and even on your server to store, organise and maintain images. For example Imgur. Stack Overflow uses Imgur to save images uploaded to it. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350433/why-does-stack-exchange-use-imgur-to-host-images 
Also, look into Firebase Cloud Storage - https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/

Comment: @MD Naseem Ashraf I would like to host images on my servers for privacy purposes

Comment: It's entirely up to you as to which way you implement image storage, I was adding that you had ready to use options. Firebase Cloud storage would be more secure than an average server, while you'd need to go the extra measure to have redundant backups of data in case of data loss or encrypting storage and other security measures. The security and features provided by cloud storage providers like Amazon and Google are preferred by bigger companies as it eases its use while maintaining the highest available security measures on the cloud. Look into your options and weigh their pro and cons.